# The non-generic method 'Dictionary<Type, Type>.Add(Type, Type)' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, repository-pattern

I have below classes and interface implementation

```
public interface IPageRepository<T> : IRepository
{
    IList<T> GetPage(Criteria criteria, out int totalRows);
}

public interface ICategoryRepository : IPageRepository<Category>
{
    // rest of the methods
}

public class CategoryRepository : BaseDap, ICategoryRepository
{
    // method implementations
}

public class RepositoryFactory
{

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> container = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    static RepositoryFactory()
    {
        container.Add<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();  

        //Getting error here:
        //The non-generic method 'Dictionary<Type, Type>.Add(Type, Type)' cannot be used with type arguments
    }
}
```

I have followed similar pattern in other project and it works there. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: If the answer given solves your problem pls accept the answer - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've confused type arguments for actual arguments. You meant to write

```
 container.Add(typeof(ICategoryRepository), typeof(CategoryRepository));
```

Comment: This worked for me. But I have similar pattern in another project. It does not give any error there. Why ?

Comment: @Lokesh: "similar" implies "different".  The difference is that the different code you wrote in a different program was *correct*, and the code you wrote in this program was *incorrect*.